# android jacoco ignores src/test directory

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, jacoco

I am trying to setup the jacoco report generator for collecting the coverage from both src/androidTest AND src/test. But unfortunatelly with no success at the moment.

This is my jacoco.gradlew file so far:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.11"
}

android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
                jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
            }
        }
    }
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {

    reports {
        csv.required = false
        xml {
            required = true
            destination file("${buildDir}/coverage-report")
        }
        html {
            required = true
            destination file("${buildDir}/coverage-report")
        }
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories.from(files([mainSrc]))
    classDirectories.from(files([debugTree]))
    executionData.from(fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/testPlayDebugUnitTest.exec",
            "outputs/code-coverage/playDebugAndroidTest/connected/*coverage.ec"
    ]))
}

tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    finalizedBy connectedAndroidTest
}
```

After running `./gradlew jacocoTestReport connectedAndroidTest` just the test for src/androidTest is generated but the tests in src/test are completely ommited.

I am using JUnit 4

This is my gradle.file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.5.0.2730'
    id 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt' version '1.23.4'
}

apply from: "$rootDir/jacoco.gradle"

android {
    [...]
    testOptions {
        packagingOptions {
            jniLibs {
                useLegacyPackaging = true
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    [...]
    testImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.5.4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.5.4'

    //kotest
    testImplementation 'io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:5.8.0'
    testImplementation 'io.kotest:kotest-property:5.8.0'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.9.21'
    testImplementation 'app.cash.turbine:turbine:0.9.0'
    testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk-android:1.13.9'
}
```

Maybe someone has figured out the solution, because I get pretty frustrated. Thx for help!